# Safari TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Object.assign(...)')

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, key-value

I would like to assign some object to a target object by Javascript Object.assign(). It works fine in chrome. In safari though I get an error.

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not a function (evaluating 'Object.assign(wkObj,tObj,list)')
```

Object

```
    var list = {'width':'100px'};
    var tz = "translateZ(-18px)";
    var tObj = {'transform': tz};
    var wkObj = {'-webkit-transform': tz};
```

Comment: it is not supported https://developer.mozilla.org/it/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign you could use the suggested polyfill

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not supported by safari, but you can always create a polyfill:

```
if (!Object.assign) {
  Object.defineProperty(Object, 'assign', {
    enumerable: false,
    configurable: true,
    writable: true,
    value: function(target, firstSource) {
      'use strict';
      if (target === undefined || target === null) {
        throw new TypeError('Cannot convert first argument to object');
      }

      var to = Object(target);
      for (var i = 1; i < arguments.length; i++) {
        var nextSource = arguments[i];
        if (nextSource === undefined || nextSource === null) {
          continue;
        }

        var keysArray = Object.keys(Object(nextSource));
        for (var nextIndex = 0, len = keysArray.length; nextIndex < len; nextIndex++) {
          var nextKey = keysArray[nextIndex];
          var desc = Object.getOwnPropertyDescriptor(nextSource, nextKey);
          if (desc !== undefined && desc.enumerable) {
            to[nextKey] = nextSource[nextKey];
          }
        }
      }
      return to;
    }
  });
}
```

Or start using a transpiler like [Babel](https://babeljs.io/)

### [Reference for polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)

Comment: Thought I was having a stroke when I opened that link, then Chrome asked me if I wanted to translate